# Getting output System.Data.DataRow[] Instead of cloumn values from data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Please find below code

```
%%[
var @City, @MyArea, @Area, @rowCount, @row
set @City = "London"
set @Area = LookupRows('Salon data','City',@City)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@Area)
if @rowCount > 0 then
    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
         set @row = row(@Area,@i)
         set @MyArea = field(@row,"Area")<>br>
                 if @i == 1 then
                      outputline(concat("<'ul>"))
                 endif
]%%
           <'li>%%=v(@Area)=%% </li>

%%[
       if @i == @rowcount then
            outputline(concat("<'/ul>"))
       endif
           next @i 
]%%
%%[ else ]%%
No rows found
%%[ endif ]%%
```

I have hardcoded lookup value for this example and it has respective 4 rows in data extension but it give me output 4 times `System.Data.DataRow[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code looks correct and you just need to pass a `@MyArea` variable instead of `@Area`

```
%%[
SET @City = "London"
SET @Area = LookupRows('Salon data','City',@City)
SET @RowCount = Rowcount(@Area)
IF @RowCount > 0 Then
    FOR @i = 1 To @RowCount Do
        SET @MyArea = Field(Row(@Area,@i),"Area")
             IF @i == 1 Then
                  OutPutLine(concat("<ul>"))
             EndIF
]%%
       <li>%%=v(@MyArea)=%% </li>
%%[
           IF @i == @RowCount Then
                OutPutLine(concat("</ul>"))
           EndIF
    Next @i 
Else 
]%%
    No rows found
%%[EndIF]%%
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.... its working.... !! It seems that you have good understanding about AMP script. Could you please look at question posted on below link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192328/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-data-extension-cloumn