# How to get distinct values from Data Extension column

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Suppose I have data extension and it has multiple rows. I want to retrieve all values from one column and get only distinct values. Please find below screenshot
[image]

I want to create a picklist which I need distinct values from the City column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll need to add a field in your Data Extension that has a static value (e.g. `LookupKey`, with a default value of `1`).  You can only do a lookup with an `equals` operator. Then you'll need to set it for your existing rows -- probably easiest with an export and overwrite import.

Once that's done, then you can use that LookupKey value in your lookup...something like this:

```
%%[

var @i, @cities, @row, @rowCount, @maxRows
var @City, @prevCity, @Area, @Salon, @Number

set @maxRows = 0 /* up to 2000 */

set @cities = LookupOrderedRows("Cities" ,@maxRows, "Number asc", "lookupKey","1")
set @rowCount = RowCount(@cities)
set @prevCity = ""

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

  set @row = Row(@cities,@i)
  set @City = Field(@row, "City")
  set @Area = Field(@row, "Area")
  set @Salon = Field(@row, "Salon")
  set @Number = Field(@row, "Number")

  if @rowCount == 1 then

    output(concat("<ul>"))

  endif 

  if empty(@prevCity) or @City != @prevCity then

     set @prevCity = @City

     output(concat("<li>",@City,"</li>"))

  endif

  if @i == @rowCount then

    output(concat("</ul>"))

  endif 


next @i 

]%%
```

**Reference**

- [**De-duplicate rows in AMPScript**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/de-duplicate-rows-ampscript/)

Comment: I have done just few changes. changed rowCount == rowcount to i == rowCount bcz that should be executed only one time during last loop counter. It seems that there is problem while displaying the output bcz when i print variable values they show output as expected but cities are not displaying....

Comment: I have changed write to outputline and it works.... You are awesome Adam..
Thanks for your help

Comment: Adam just small question..  Can i use variable from AMP script in client side javascript??  Suppose if i want to use city in javascript how can i do this??

Comment: Yes, you can pass values back and forth between SSJS and AMPScript, but keep in mind SSJS and AMPScript are both _server-side_, so they're evaluated before the page is displayed, not after like regular, client-side JavaScript.