# AMPscript LookUp search records for specific days

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I have a date format in the DE that includes minutes and seconds (4/09/2021 11:45:18 AM). I only need to search and show the records of a certain day (format; MM / D / YYYY). DateParse and FormatDate functions don't work for me

```
set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("lookupField")
                   set @lookupValue = '09/4/2021'
```

[image]

Comment: quick suggestion use sql to populate a text field with only the date part you want to lookup on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMPscript lookup criteria pairs only use `=` operators -- it doesn't handle `>` or `<`.

You'll need to either loop through all of the rows and check each one with an AMPscript conditional or do as [@EazyE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/66853/eazye) suggested, and create columns in your DE that match 1:1 with the criteria you'll need to select the rows exactly.

I usually just create a `lookupKey` column in my DE and default its value to `1` and then lookup for every row that matches `1`.  [Here's](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192328/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-data-extension-column/192350#192350) an example.